# Cookie get deleted/set to null after redirect

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, setcookie

I am using cookie in a page to record the user's input in a form. After the user login, i want to automatically fill in the form by using their old cookie.

Basically, i want to record some cookies, and let user login, and output the cookies.

In the first page, I set the cookies, however, after I redirect with

> window.location.href

My cookies just recorded are set to null/deleted automatically.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: post some codes where you are setting your cookies

Comment: -1 this question cannot be answered without additional information, and you're not giving us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If everyone else meets same problems, this is simply because the cookie's path problem.

When you set the cookie, do this :

> `$.cookie('the_cookie', 'the_value', { expires: 7, path: '/' });`

So the cookie can be cross-pages.

:]